# PDFKit PDFSelecction bounding box coordinate system

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

I'm want to find a specific word in a pdf and draw a bounding box on it.
To do it I use

```
func findString(_ string: String, 
withOptions options: NSString.CompareOptions = []) -> [PDFSelection]
```

What is the coordinate system of the PDFSelection?
I want to draw the bounding box (property of the pdfselection) on top of the pdfview and obtain the rectangles in an awkward place.

Does anybody know how to transform this coordinates?

This is my code

```
let searchResult = document.findString("VAT", withOptions: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

for result in searchResult {
    let box = result(for: document.page(at: 0)!)
    let convertedBox = pdf.convert(box, from: document.page(at: 0)!)
    let boxView = UIView(frame: convertedBox)
    boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.6, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0.5)
    view.addSubview(boxView)
    print(box)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to add a highlight on the text?

Comment: I'm trying to find the location of it.

Answer (score 2):

The `PDFSelection` is a location in the page(s) where the match found

The bounds of this selection is relative to the page itself.

here is an example of getting the bounds and then using that to add an annotation

```
let searchResult = document.findString("VAT", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)

for result in searchResult {

    let bounds = result.pages.map { result.bounds(for: $0)) }

    let annotations = bounds.map { PDFAnnotation(bounds: $0, forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil) }

    annotations.forEach { $0.page?.addAnnotation($0) }
}
```

Please note that the match might be found in two pages or more if the text was long continues to the next page

In the example above the color of the annotation can be set by: `PDFAnnotation.color` property

The `PDFView` contains a `UIScrollView` which you can get by this extension:

```
extension PDFView {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
        return subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView
    }
}
```

then try to calculate the actual frame my adding the size of the previous pages and then that should be the frame to add inside the scrollview

Comment: I'm trying to draw a box (with the bounds property) on the search results and to find the closest box (which will be done on another search. The boxes are drawn everywhere but not on the result word.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but your code is not working for me. Nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @CarlosMariaCaraccia check the update if you're using `PDFView`

Comment: There is only one page in my document (one invoice) and it does not works, thanks a lot, I don't want to make you loose your time. I have also tried the convert function in quartz and it did not work too.